# I want different text in the same line positioned to the left and right inside a table cell

Tags: html, css, web, paragraph

I am making a school timetable mock in HTML and CSS and I am having troubles with one specific thing and that is having 2 different pieces of text in the same line one positioned to the top left and the other to the top right. I have tried using float but that makes the text move down to text that is under it.

Here is the code used:
https://jsfiddle.net/zhu2a1y4/

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <table class="separated">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='cell_header'>
                    <p class="group">s1</p>
                    <p class="classroom">N228</p>
                <div>
                <h3>S: ICT</h3>
                <p>KOH</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>s1 N228</p>
                <h3>L: ICT</h3>
                <p>KOH</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
*{
padding: 0px;
}
table, td {
    border: solid black 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    column-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
.separated td, .separated{
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell_header p {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.classroom{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
.group{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;}
```

As you can see in the example the text "s1" and "N228" are Next to "S:ICT" and my objective is to have both of the pieces of text higher up in the corners.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance and best regards

Davza

Comment: you are using table then why float? you can simply use td to make them in one line. right? just remove extra tr head and create one tr and you will get what you want to.

Comment: the reason for having two tr's is because I want the two cells separated the way they are, I am only wanting the "s1" and N228 moved up and don't know how. It might just be that I do not understand what you mean by your answer. If you could provide a more detailed and informative answer It might help me understand thank you. @Leothelion

Comment: if i am not wrong then you want to have S1 N228 S:ICT  and in front of them another S1 N228 L:ICT in left and right, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you are using floats for a table, but still, the solution to your problem is simple. Just add this to your css and you are good to go.

```
.classroom{
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
.group{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}
```

**How did this solve the problem?**
--> It's simple, you are setting the positions of those two elements to be relative, and then change the top to `-15px` so the text goes 15px above its original position.

**Also**, if you want to change how high the elements should go, just change the `top: ;` value to whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It has helped a ton. As regarding your question why I use float for a table. Well the answer is such that I am just starting out with html and css at school and even though we have gone over tables to a certain extent this is a topic our teacher has not covered so I have to go off of the information I find on the internet and float is something that I have found being thrown around a lot so I figured it would be the right way to go. If you would be so kind to take the time and direct me to some sources that I could learn from It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also I hope it would not be too much hassle telling me how I could position the .group and .classroom relative to the table cell so it stays in the same position? Your answer works great but this is something that I could use for future projects.

Comment: Even i am a student who has basic knowledge of html css and basic js... using floats for tweaking stuff is fine but for alignment, you should use flexbox or css grid, the best place to learn those is w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp or you could learn it from youtube 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSoEo8JSnc 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o

ps: if you want to position .group and classroom relative to the table cell and not to themselves then change the position to `position: absolute;`

Comment: and i apologize for replying so late... i had my exams so i wasnt able to surf the internet for the time